# Is dependency injection possible for JSP beans?

Tags: java, jsp, dependency-injection, pojo

This may be a long shot question..

I am working on an application that is based on JSP/Javascript only (without a Web framework!)

Is there a way to have depencency injection for JSP beans?
By jsp beans I mean beans defined like this

```
<jsp:useBean id="cart" scope="session" class="session.Carts" />
```

Is there a way/library/hack to intercept the bean creation so that when "cart" is referenced for the first time, some some of injection takes place?

Can I define somewhere a "listener" for JSP beans (like you can do for JSF beans for example)?

I am free to do anything I want in the back-end, but I cannot add a web framework in the front-end (Don't ask!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, with spring and AspectJ - using `@Configurable` and `<context:load-time-weaver/>` (read the [aop section of spring docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop.html#aop-aj-ltw))

Comment: Nice! I never thought that it was possible! You have deep knowledge of everything Java related.